# Wrong collisions(bouncing) in rigid body physics with 3 objects

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision, rigidbody

I want a beam being in stable position then move cylinder to another side of pit in beam so higher end of beam goes to floor then do the same but in opposite direction and repeat it multiple times. Like [photo from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seesaw#/media/File:Seesaw-aa.jpg), [article from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seesaw). But the cylinder sets it in motion by moving in space of pit in beam. Also cylinder follows a line of pit in beam, so cylinder moves to floor each iteration of cycle, motion is like going [left of right] and down in a line.

I tried, sometimes it was falling through floor, but the current problem that beam bounces or jumps off.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

always apply scale if you are using simulations (like physics), so select your cube, then press CTRL-A -> Scale. Then start simulation again.

[image]